# Is there a linq equivalent to raw sql for paging

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I think the following efficiently works whether there are 10 records or 10 million records. Is there a linq equivalent that works like this?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new pubsEntities())
            {
                //this will throw an exception
                var studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<employee>(@"
;with CTE AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by emp_id) AS RowNumber
FROM employee
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber > 2 AND RowNumber <= (2 + 4)
                ").ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `IQueryable<T>.Skip(x).Take(x)` to simulate Paging.**

Its pretty simple.  If we're looking at your code, you'd want something like this:

```
var pageSize = 100;
var startPage = 2;
var skipAmount = pageSize * startPage;
ctx.Database.Employee.Skip(skipAmount).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: but doesn't this slow down if there are 10 million records?

Comment: @Rod not if the linq provider translates it properly

Comment: in my case it is using offset keyword in the SQL. So if I wanted to the last page of 10 million records the offset would be like 9+ million. That wouldn't be a slow offset or does it matter?

Comment: @Rod I actually don't know off hand.  I have used it up to 1 million records without issue.  In the guts of Entity Framework (which is what I assumed is being used here) it'll generate optimized code per EF's rules then the SQL Optimizer will get a hold of it.  I'll take a peek here and see if I can tell what query would ultimately run against the server.